# Pasar de "Future<mi_clase>" a "mi_clase" en Flutter

Tags: json, flutter

Hola estoy obteniendo un json desde un servidor, recibo todo los datos en eso no tengo problema, mi problema surge una vez obtenido como puedo pasarlo a mi **clase RecetaList**  , solo puedo pasarlo a **Future <RecetaList>**, hay alguna manera de pasar todo el **json** a mi clase para trabajarlo mejor en los Widget. En especial quiero desplegarlo toda la informacion en un **ListView.builder**.

> Este es el metodo que me rescata la informacion desde el servidor,
>   aqui no tengo problemas:

```
Future<RecetaList> fetchFavoritos() async {
  final response =await http.get('https://recetas-inf422.herokuapp.com/');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // Si la llamada al servidor fue exitosa, analiza el JSON
       return RecetaList.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
}
```

> Despues en mi clase:

```
class _TrendingState extends State<Trending> {
  Future<RecetaList> recetado;
  RecetaList receta1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    recetado = fetchFavoritos();
    receta1= fetchFavoritos(); //Aqui es donde me da un error
  }
}
```

> EL problema se presenta aqui:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    recetado = fetchFavoritos();
    receta1= fetchFavoritos(); //Aqui es donde me da un error
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando funciones/métodos asíncronos dentro de una función que no está marcada como asíncrona.

Tienes 2 opciones:

1-

Crea un método aparte, márcalo como asíncrono, y espera la respuesta usando `await`.

```dart
your_async_method() async {
 recetado = await fetchFavoritos();
 //puedes llamar a setState aquí para refrescar el widget
}

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   your_async_method();
  }
```

2-

Espera el future sin la palabra reservada `await` (es menos legible).

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     fetchFavoritos().then((value) {
         recetado = value;
        //puedes llamar a setState aquí para refrescar el widget
   });
  }
```

**UPDATE**

Esto considerando que tu variable `recetado` es `RecetaList`:

```dart
RecetaList recetado;
```

También podrías usar directamente el widget `FutureBuilder` en tu arbol de widgets, ya que `fetchFavoritos` retorna un `Future`.

Te recomiendo este video del equipo de Flutter donde explican sobre Futures y async

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTS-ap9_aXc